# How to take 2 characters from std::string and convert it to int in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, type-conversion, stdstring

In C++, I have a string, such that `std::string string = "1234567890"`.

and I have a vector of integers defined as `std::vector<int> vec`

How can I compute `vec = stoi(string.at(1) + string.at(2))` so it will give me the integer `12` that I can insert to this vector?

Comment: `stoi` returns an integer. How do you want assign that to `vec`. I don't understand what you try to do.

Comment: do you want to convert the whole string to one number, or two characters at a time or what exactly ?

Comment: I really didn't understand the post and the title could have been written better :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is by extracting substrings rather than individual characters. Use `operator +` to concetanate them, and call `stoi` on the resulting string:

```
vec.push_back(stoi(string.substr(0, 1) + string.substr(1, 1)));
// vec now ends with 12
```

The above will concatenate strings at arbitrary locations in the source string. If you really need only extract consecutive characters, a single call to `substr` will suffice:

```
vec.push_back(stoi(string.substr(0, 2)));
```

Comment: Since they are one after the other, would `vec.push_back(atoi(string.substr(0,2)))` work?

Comment: This depends on what you want. Your question is not clear about that.

Comment: @NictraSavios Yes; I've edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: `atoi(string.substr(0, 2).c_str())` = `stoi(string.substr(0, 2))` (which was already used in the question)

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand, you want to retrieve the first 2 characters as a string, convert it to `int` and insert to the vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::string str = "1234567890";

// retrieve the number:
int i;
std::istringstream(str.substr(0,2)) >> i;

// insert it to the vector:
vec.push_back(i);
```

With C++11 support, you might use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead of string stream.

Comment: is C++11 support needed for `std::stoi` ... ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi: Yes, however in C++03 there is [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) as well.

Comment: I used a different awnser, since I don't like the idea of streams, but I did use the C++11 methods stoi and to_string in my program.

Answer (score 3):

Use a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss(string.substr(0,2));
int number;
ss >> number;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have correctly understood you you want to form an integer number from the first two characters of the string. Then it can be done the following way

```
std::vector<int> vec = { ( ( s.length() >= 1 && is_digit( s[0] ) ) ? s[0] - '0' : 0 ) * 10 +
                         ( ( s.length() > 1 && is_digit( s[1] ) ) ? s[1] - '0' : 0 ) };
```

The general approach is the following

```
std::string s = "123456789";
std::vector<int> v( 1, std::accumulate( s.begin(), s.end(), 0,
    []( int acc, char c ) { return ( isdigit( c ) ? 10 * acc + c - '0' : acc ); } ) );

std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
```

All you need is to specify the required range of iterators for the string.